# Optimize the Game - Make Fair Game with Biased Coins

Tags: probability, statistics

The traditional question states that given an unfair coin, with 0.7 probability of heads, how would you make a fair game? The answer is only consider two outcomes. If two trials yields $HT$ then the player wins, else if $TH$ the player loses.

Now the interesting part is the follow-up question. If now my head probability is 0.99, how should one go about optimizing making a fair game out of this coin? "Optimizing" means to come up with a fair game with minimal amount of coin tosses.

The original approach is inefficient, because most of the outcome would be $HH$, with probability $0.99^2$). The probability of $HT$ or $TH$ would be relatively small.

Comment: What do you mean by "optimize" in this context?

Comment: "Optimize" means to come up with a fair game using as few number of experiments as possible.

Comment: In the case you give where only the outcomes HT and TH are relevant, we have an expected waiting time of about $50$ trials, or $100$ coin tosses.  Which measure are you using, $50$ or $100$?

Comment: This is not relevant, as the question is asking the method one should use for optimizing the game. In the eyes of the optimization problem, minimizing the number of trials and minimizing the number of total coin tosses would be equivalent problems.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  If some protocol uses $7$ coin tosses and another uses $11$, how can you say that minimizing the number of experiments is the same as minimizing the number of coin tosses?

Comment: Ok then, please use the total number of coin tosses as a measure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98003/discussion-between-kemeng-zhang-and-saulspatz).

Answer (score 6):

Each coin flip provides $-P \log_2 P = 0.0143546$ bits of information (uncertainty), and you seek $1$ bit of uncertainty.  Thus you need at least $1/.0143546 \approx 69$ such tosses.  This is perfectly efficient and the laws of information ensure you cannot do better than that.

Comment: Thanks David! I was wondering if the exact amount of information provided by each coin flip is $-P\log_2 P-(1-P)\log_2 (1-P)$. Moreover, do you happen to know a strategy that can approximately achieve the 69 tosses lower bound?

Comment: The calculation seems wrong - first, the information provided by each flip is -plogp - (1-p)log(1-p) = 0.081, so you missed the second term. And even with your expression, the exact number is 0.066

Answer (score 4):

The probability of flipping 69 consecutive heads is $(.99)^{69}=0.4998+$.  I'm prepared to be surprised, but I suspect that means that you can't arrange an experiment in fewer than 69 flips that would have a 50% chance of success.